# sending form data in modal without redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form in a modal. It includes a file and some data. When I click submit, it redirects to target page of the form. I want the data to be sent to the target page without being redirected to it and the modal should close.

I have tried this but didn't work:

```js
    $("form#data").submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.post($(this).attr("doupload.php"), formData, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });

    return false;
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">File Details</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p><form id='data' action='doupload.php' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">

             <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td width="80%"><input type="text" name='modalTitle' id="modalTitle" maxlength="50" required='required'></td>
                <td><div  id="modalTitlError" ></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject</td>
                <td><input type="text" name='modalSubject' id="modalSubject" maxlength="30" required='required'></td>
                <td id="modalSubjectError"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Topics</td>
                <td><textarea rows="3" cols="100" name='modalTopics' id="modalTopics" style="width: 100%" maxlength="200" required='required'> </textarea></td>
                <td id="modalTopicsError"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required='required'>
            <button>Submit</button>
            </td></tr>

    </table>
    </form>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `url` name given to post request is not correct, use :

```
$.post($(this).attr("action"), formData, function(data) {
//OR
$.post('doupload.php', formData, function(data) {
```

Instead of :

```
$.post($(this).attr("doupload.php"), formData, function(data) {
```

Hope this helps.